# how to build and simplify Java code for Android

Tags: java, android, database, search, android-room

How can I simplify all this code?
I am creating a search menu and I want to check the values when the user exits a 'Text View' and display the output immediately as a 'Recycle Viewer' below.

- **One way is to do this with a very large number of IFs.** Do you suggest
  another method?
- I use the Roon Library for my application database.

I wanted to use this code for this but I saw that the number of IFs is very high.

- **A friend suggested using Case in the database, but I do not know how to write its code!**

  ```
       public void searchHelper() {
       String sOperationValue = spinnerOperation.getText().toString();
       String sTraderValue = spinnerTraderName.getText().toString();
       String sSearchByValue = spinnerSearchBy.getText().toString();
       long startValue = Long.parseLong(etStartDate.getText().toString());
       long endValue = Long.parseLong(etEndDate.getText().toString());

       // * * * * *
       if (!sOperationValue.isEmpty() &&
               !sTraderValue.isEmpty() &&
               !sSearchByValue.isEmpty() &&
               startValue >= 14000000 &&
               endValue <= 15000000) {

       }
       // * - * * *
       if (!sOperationValue.isEmpty() &&
               sTraderValue.isEmpty() &&
               !sSearchByValue.isEmpty() &&
               startValue >= 14000000 &&
               endValue <= 15000000) {

       }
       // * - - - -
       if (!sOperationValue.isEmpty() &&
               sTraderValue.isEmpty() &&
               sSearchByValue.isEmpty() &&
               startValue <= 0 &&
               endValue <= 0) {

       }
       // - * * * *
       if (sOperationValue.isEmpty() &&
               !sTraderValue.isEmpty() &&
               !sSearchByValue.isEmpty() &&
               startValue >= 14000000 &&
               endValue <= 15000000) {

       }
       // Here 'Search By' specifies whether the search should be based on the date of registration or on the date of the transaction.
       // Therefore, when Search By is empty, then the start date and end date values are also empty.
       // - * - - -
       if (sOperationValue.isEmpty() &&
               !sTraderValue.isEmpty() &&
               sSearchByValue.isEmpty() &&
               startValue <= 0 &&
               endValue <= 0) {

       }
       // - - * * *
       if (sOperationValue.isEmpty() &&
               sTraderValue.isEmpty() &&
               !sSearchByValue.isEmpty() &&
               startValue >= 14000000 &&
               endValue <= 15000000) {

       }
       // - - - - -
       if (sOperationValue.isEmpty() &&
               sTraderValue.isEmpty() &&
               sSearchByValue.isEmpty() &&
               startValue <= 0 &&
               endValue <= 0) {

       }
   }
  ```
- **I also wanted to write a query using Case but failed.** This was the code I wrote

  ```
   @Query("SELECT * FROM tbl_transaction" +
       " WHERE CASE WHEN operation='null'" +
       " THEN CASE WHEN traderName='null'" +
       " THEN CASE WHEN transactionType ='null'" +
       " THEN CASE WHEN startDate=14000000" +
       " THEN CASE WHEN endDate=15000000" )
       List<Transaction> getSearchValues(String operation, String traderName, String transactionType, long startDate, long endDate);
  ```

***Although I was very much looking for the right solution, I unfortunately could not find it.***

**Thank you in advance for your help.**

[image: Form Image]

Comment: Try looking at [how to replace many if statements in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-replace-if-statements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I shortened it for you, this is not the best way to do it but it still works

I will make a shorter version of it but it will take some time since it will be more complicated to make:

```
public void searchHelper() {
    boolean b1 = spinnerOperation.getText().toString()isEmpty();
    boolean b2 = spinnerTraderName.getText().toString()isEmpty();
    boolean b3 = spinnerSearchBy.getText().toString()isEmpty();
    boolean b4 = Long.parseLong(etStartDate.getText().toString()) >= 14000000 && Long.parseLong(etEndDate.getText().toString()) <= 15000000;
     boolean b5 = Long.parseLong(etStartDate.getText().toString()) <= 0 && Long.parseLong(etEndDate.getText().toString()) <= 0;

     // * * * * *
     if (!b1 && !b2 && !b3 && b4) {

     }
     // * - * * *
     if (!b1 && b2 && !b3 && b4) {

     }
     // * - - - -
     if (!b1 && b2 && b3 && b5) {

     }
     // - * * * *
     if (b1 && !b2 && !b3 && b4) {

     }
     // Here 'Search By' specifies whether the search should be based on the date of registration or on the date of the transaction.
     // Therefore, when Search By is empty, then the start date and end date values are also empty.
     // - * - - -
     if (b1 && !b2 && b3 && b5) {

     }
     // - - * * *
     if (b1 && b2 && !b3 && b4) {

     }
  // - - - - -
    if (b1 && b2 && b3 && b5) {

  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

OperationType, TraderName, SearchBy all look like Spinners. Where are you getting the data to populate the options. If its hardcoded into the app depending on how you implement its unlikely they will be ever empty since there is always a default option selected. You may not need to check if they are empty. Then you will mostly be focusing on the startDate and endDate Edittexts. You could then improve further by using Date pickers instead.